# OSM: How to include state boundaries in iframe?

Tags: iframe, openstreetmap

I have a location needs to be shown on map with its boundaries. Like on the image

[Map should have been like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdCZK.png)

By default using OSM share link like this:

`<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-82.69546508789062%2C27.807498401524754%2C-82.21412658691406%2C28.18098087972553&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>`

doesn't show the boundary (the orange border on the image). I have tried added `q`, `bounded`, and all other param said in the [wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLinkMap). Is it possible to add that orange border in the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looked at the wiki page of [Open*Link*Map](http://www.openlinkmap.org/) which is based on OSM but a separate project. I'm afraid it's not that easy to display the boundary in an iframe the way you are trying to.

The OSM website uses [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to draw the [slippy map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map) including the [relation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) for the [state boundary](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1216849). See the [Leaflet quick start guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) which describes how to display polygons. Alternatively to Leaflet you could use [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).

Depending in the tool you might first have to [download the full relation for your state boundary](http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/1216849/full) and convert it to a polygon yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I looked around again and I think there is a way to get the state boundary data as json/xml with an api. Any pointers for that?